# Why Avalon-Framework was closed?

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, separation-of-concerns

I've stated work on new project. And started investigation all application that used. And I found one application that use avalon projects (avalon-framework, avalon-excalibur, avalon-repository, etc.). And I was realy surprised when I found that those projects were closed.

I'm very new in those technologies. Unfortunately, I didn't find the reason why they were closed. I know that they realized Inversion of Control (IoC) and Separation of Concerns (SoC) design patterns.

Does anyone know why they were closed? And which alternatives were created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say,   due to lack of interest.  There was a lot of DI frameworks  like avalon  - notably:   pico/nanocontainer,   guice, spring -  and spring eventually won  and is most 
used now.  You do not develop a framework if you have no use case for it.

But nevertheless, the ideas are not dead and found their way into mainstream (even Java EE has dependency injection now)